# Avoiding redundancy in C macros

Tags: c

I am having some redundancy in C code, which I would like to avoid.

```
// Q15 macros
#define SCALE_FACTOR_Q15 ( 0x00008000UL )
#define Q15_MAX          ( 0x00007FFFUL )
#define f32_Q15_x(x)     ( (f32)(int) ( (float)(x)*(float)SCALE_FACTOR_Q15 ) )
#define f32_Q15_MAX      ( (f32)      ( Q15_MAX )                            )
// etc...

// Q31 macros
#define SCALE_FACTOR_Q31 ( 0x80000000UL )
#define Q31_MAX          ( 0x7FFFFFFFUL )
#define f32_Q31_x(x)     ( (f32)(int) ( (float)(x)*(float)SCALE_FACTOR_Q31 ) )
#define f32_Q31_MAX      ( (f32)      ( Q31_MAX )                            )
// etc...
```

Now I need to do the same peace of code for `Q25`, and in the future probably for other `Qx`, where `x` is in range `[1,63]`.

How could I avoid writing this separately for each `Qx`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about this?

```
#define SCALE_FACTOR_Q(N) ( 1UL << N )
#define Q_MAX(N)          ( SCALE_FACTOR_Q(N) - 1 )
#define f32_Q_x(N,x)      ( (f32)(int) ( (float)(x)*(float)SCALE_FACTOR_Q(N) ) )
#define f32_Q_MAX(N)      ( (f32)Q_MAX(N) )
```

Comment: And to avoid specifing `N` every time, something like: `#define f32_Q15_x(x)   f32_Q_x(15, x)`?